# Как в Modx сделать систему категорий товаров, но не через TV?

Tags: modx

Хочу сделать на сайте систему категорий. Один товар может быть в нескольких категориях. Например, товар «Стол L456» есть в категориях «Мебель для дома», «Мебель для офиса», «Компьютерные столы».

Я пробовал делать категории через TV (TV — чекбоксы. И значения этого TV — ресурсы, которые отвечают за категории товаров. То есть, я могу в товаре поставить чекбокс «Мебель для дома», «Мебель для офиса», «Компьютерные столы». И он будет принадлежать к этим категориям). Неплохой вариант. Но хочется что-то другое.

Я пробовал делать через символические ссылки. Но тогда надо копировать все TV товара (цена, картинка...). Да и если добавить этот симлинк в корзину через ShopKeeper, то симлинк и оригинальный товар будут разными товарами.

Какой есть еще способ сделать категории?

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение Collection. Можно создать ресурс (тип ресурса = подборка), а в нем привязать необходимые позиции.